# ASP.NET UpdatePanel: Injecting Javascript on UpdatePanel update

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel, javascript-injection

**Are there any potential side-effects** to below solution to injecting JavaScript from the content of an updated `UpdatePanel`?

The code for the `UpdatePanel` looks sort of like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="pnlScriptContent" Visible="false" runat="server">
        <script id="script-content">
            alert('Script was loaded correctly!');
        </script>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <asp:Button OnClick="ButtonClick" OnClientClick="LoadScript()" />
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The code-behind on the click of the `Button` shows the Panel `pnlScriptContent`.

```
protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    pnlScriptContent.Visible = true;
}
```

The JavaScript-code looks like this:

```
var LoadScript = function() {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function (sender, args) {
        eval($('#script-content').html());
    };
}
```

I've seen other solutions to inject JavaScript after an UpdatePanel updates, but nothing that allows the injection of JavaScript inside `script`-tags in the content.

Is there a reason to this? Security maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb350750.aspx) static method of the `ScriptManager` class